# MySQL hanging on large SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new table by joining four existing ones.  My database is static, so making one large preprocessed table will simplify programming, and save lots of time in future queries.  My query works fine when limited with a `WHERE`, but seems to either hang, or go too slowly to notice any progress.

Here's the working query.  The result only takes a few seconds.

```
SELECT group.group_id, MIN(application.date), person.person_name, pers_appln.sequence
FROM group
JOIN application ON group.appln_id=application.appln_id
JOIN pers_appln ON pers_appln.appln_id=application.appln_id
JOIN person ON person.person_id=pers_appln.person_id
WHERE group_id="24601"
GROUP BY group.group_id, pers_appln.sequence
;
```

If I simply remove the `WHERE` line, it will run for days with nothing to show.  Adding a `CREATE TABLE newtable AS` at the beginning does the same thing.  It never moves beyond 0% progress.

The group, application, and person tables all use the MyISAM engine, while pers_appln uses InnoDB.  The columns are all indexed.  The table sizes range from about 40 million to 150 million rows.  I know it's rather large, but I wouldn't think it would pose this much of a problem.  The computer currently has 4GB of ram.

Any ideas how to make this work?

---

Here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` info.  There are no views or virtual tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `APPLN_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_appln` (`APPLN_ID`),
  KEY `idx_group` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `application` (
  `APPLN_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `APPLN_AUTH` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `APPLN_NR` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `APPLN_KIND` char(2) DEFAULT '',
  `DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `IPR_TYPE` char(2) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`APPLN_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8



CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `PERSON_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PERSON_CTRY_CODE` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `PERSON_NAME` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERSON_ADDRESS` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_person` (`PERSON_ID`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 MAX_ROWS=30000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=100


CREATE TABLE `pers_appln` (
  `PERSON_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `APPLN_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SEQUENCE` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLACE` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_pers_appln` (`APPLN_ID`),
  KEY `idx_person` (`PERSON_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (appln_id)
PARTITIONS 20 */
```

---

Here's the `EXPLAIN` of my query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys              | key             | key_len | ref                      | rows     | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | person      | ALL    | idx_person                 | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                     | 47827690 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pers_appln  | ref    | idx_application,idx_person | idx_person      | 4       | mydb.person.PERSON_ID    |        1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | application | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY         | 4       | mydb.pers_appln.APPLN_ID |        1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | group       | ref    | idx_application            | idx_application | 4       | mydb.pers_appln.APPLN_ID |        1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+----------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Does your machine have enough memory to execute this? You could be encountering a bunch of disk IOs. Also, what table does "sequence" belong to? Could you create an index on group_id,sequence?

Comment: Creating this cross-product between such large tables will result in a very large intermediate table.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by "cross-product"?

Comment: @Rachie you need to provide `EXPLAIN` + `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table in the query.

Comment: A `JOIN` is a cross-product between the tables, filtered by the `ON` conditions.

Comment: If proper indices are in place, the join would be done on the fly.

Comment: This query would produce an error. Can we see the actual query?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that key_buffer_size is about 200M and innodb_buffer_pool_size is about 1200M.  Perhaps they could be bigger, but make sure you are not swapping.

`group` should have `PRIMARY KEY(appln_id, group_id)` and `INDEX(group_id, appln_id)` instead of the two KEYs it has.

`pers_appln` should have `INDEX(person_id, appln_id)` and `INDEX(appln_id, person_id)` instead of the two keys it has.  If possible, one of those should be PRIMARY KEY, but watch out for the PARTITIONing.

A minor improvement would be to change those CHAR(2) fields to be CHARACTER SET ascii -- assuming you don't really need utf8.  That would shrink the field from 6 bytes to 2 bytes per row.

The PARTITIONing is probably not helping at all.  (No, I can't say that removing the PARTITIONing will speed it up much.)

If these suggestions do not help enough, please provide the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

**Edit**

Converting to InnoDB *and* specifying PRIMARY KEYs for all tables will help.  This is because InnoDB "clusters" the PRIMARY KEY with the data.  What you have now is a lot of bouncing between a MyISAM index and its data -- literally hundreds of millions of times.  Assuming not everything can be cached in your small 4GB, that means a lot of disk I/O.  I would not be surprised if the non-WHERE version would take a week to run.  Even with InnoDB, there will be I/O, but some of it will be avoided because:
1. reaching into a table with the PK gets the data without another disk hit.
2. the extra indexes I proposed will avoid hitting the data, again avoiding an extra disk hit.
(Millions of references * "an extra disk hit" = days of time.)

If you switch all of your tables to InnoDB, you should lower key_buffer_size to 20M and raise innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1500M.  (These are approximate; do not raise them so high that there is any swapping.)

Comment: I changed the key buffer and pool size, with no effect.  I added the `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Comment: What percent of the `group` rows have `group_id="24601"`?

Comment: Does that EXPLAIN reflect with? or without? the WHERE clause?

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` is without the `WHERE`.  I only used the `WHERE` to help write and test the query.

Comment: And you want to get a resultset of 40M rows?  That will take a lot of time regardless.  My suggestions will speed it up, but it still will take minutes, maybe hours.

Comment: Hours is perfectly fine.  Anything would be better than letting it run for days, and still have 0% progress.

Comment: If that "0%" is coming from the PROCESSLIST, I would not trust it too much.

Comment: After converting everything to InnoDB and fixing the keys, it still won't run in a reasonable time.  By testing smaller ranges in the `WHERE` clause, I estimate it would take 45 days.  Any more ideas?

Comment: Let's take a broader look at this.  What will you do with the 47 million rows?  Perhaps more of the task can be pushed into SQL, and we find a way make that run adequately fast.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the CREATE TABLEs with InnoDB -- I want to make sure each table has a PRIMARY KEY and which column(s) that is.  The PRIMARY KEY makes a *big* difference in this particular situation.

For `person`, the MyISAM version has just a `KEY(person_id)`.  If you did not change the keys in the conversions, InnoDB will invent a PRIMARY KEY.  When the JOIN to that table occurs, InnoDB will (1) drill down the BTree for `key` to find that invented PK value, then (2) drill down the PK+data BTree to find the row.  If, instead, `person_id` could be the PK, that JOIN would run twice as fast.  Possibly even faster--depending on how big the table is and how much it needs to jump around in the index / data.  That is, the two BTree lookups is adding to the pressure on the cache (buffer_pool).

How big is each table?  What was the final value for innodb_buffer_pool_size?  Once you have changed everything from MyISAM to InnoDB, set key_buffer_size to 40M or less, and set innodb_buffer_pool_size to about 70% of available RAM.  If the Data + Index sizes for all the tables are less than the buffer_pool, then (once cache is primed) the query won't have to do any I/O.  This is easily a 10x speedup.

`pers_appln` is a many-to-many relationship?  Then, probably

```
PRIMARY KEY(appln_id, person_id),
INDEX(person_id, appln_id) -- if you need to go the other direction, too.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: switching to an SSD.  My table creation time went from an estimated 45 days to 16 hours.  Previously, the database spent all its time with hard drive I/O, barely even using 5% of the CPU or RAM.

Thanks everyone.